# ServiceStack registration

Tags: servicestack, registration

I created a custom RegistrationFeature:

```
public class CustomRegistrationFeature: IPlugin
{
    private string AtRestPath {get; set;}
    public CustomRegistrationFeature ()
    {
       AtRestPath = "/register";
    }
    public void Register (IAppHost apphost)
    {
      appHost.RegisterService <CustomRegistrationService>(AtRestPath);
      appHost.RegisterAs <CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator <CustomRegistration>>();
    }
}
```

I configured in AppHost:

```
Plugins.Add (new CustomRegistrationFeature ());
```

but in the metadata page there are CustomRegistration and Registration.
Why?
Thanks.

Update

The CustomRegistrationService:

```
[DefaultRequest(typeof(CustomRegistration))]
public class CustomRegistrationService : RegistrationService
{
    public object Post(CustomRegistration request)
    {
        //base.Post( request);
        return new CustomRegistrationResponse();
    }
}
```

The CustomRegistration (Request dto):

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomRegistration : IReturn<CustomRegistrationResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name{ get; set; } 
}
```

The CustomRegistrationResponse (Response dto):

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomRegistrationResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **CustomRegistration** service should appear although as we can't see the implementation of it, I can't tell if the service has been written correctly or not.

But there's no reason why **Registration** would appear in the `/metadata` pages since you haven't registered the [RegistrationFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RegistrationFeature.cs).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added my CustomRegistration service